# Automatic line break within string literal

Tags: string, vim, newline

When I am programming in Vim, I would like to prevent line breaking within a string literal. In other words, with `set textwidth = 80`

```
testVariable = myFunction(a=var1, b=var2, c=var3, text="This should not break to
                      the next line but does", end="this should be on the
                      next line")
```

should instead wrap as follows:

```
testVariable = myFunction(a=var1, b=var2, c=var3, text="This should not break to the next line but does",
                          end="this should be on the next line")
```

Are there vimrc options or plugins that I can use to accomplish this? If it matters, I am programming in python.

Comment: Similar to http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/839.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to prevent wrapping in specific cases, but you can certainly make your life easier by adding `set formatoptions+=b` to your vimrc. [`'formatoptions'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27formatoptions%27) describe how Vim formats the text. `b` there [means](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table) that Vim will only split lines that were shorter than `'textwidth'` to begin with.

With that, your workflow will look like this:

1. Start typing your long string.
2. When it wraps, quit Insert mode and join it all back into one line (<kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>; you know about [J](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#J), right?).
3. Keep typing. Vim won't try to wrap this line anymore (unless you trim it back under the limit of `'textwidth'`.)